# Formatting date does not follow localisation settings!

Tags: ee2, language, date-format

**Although I have set in the CP the localisation settings to Swedish,** also for superadin and my users, and I have installed the **Swedish foreign language** pack the date formattings in my Templates still are English, this is unwanted I cannot work with this.

Day 4 in the week should be 'torsdag' **(=Swedish)** but it remains 'Thursday'.

I do not understand how this really works.
Is there a simple native way to solve this?

Thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localisation settings only adjusts the language in the control panel. I can recommend the add on [Date/Time Language Converter](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/date-time-language-converter) to adjust dates to the correct language in your templates.

Comment: You are welcome!